# R appears to fail to execute a line in a function

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm a bit puzzled. I have a created a custom function:

```
doGraph <- function(x){
dev.new();
symb <- getSymbols(x, auto.assign = FALSE);
chartSeries(symb, subset = 'last 3 months', name=x);
addBBands();
addMACD();
}
doGraph("AAPL")
```

The above code does not add the Bollinger Bands, as I would expect (by the `addBBands()` call). However, if I remove the `addMACD()` call, the bands are added as expected. Additionally, if I type `addBBands()` after the function call, the bands are added. Does anyone have any thoughts on what could be going wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `plot` around your `add*` calls

```
doGraph <- function(x){
  dev.new()
  symb <- getSymbols(x, auto.assign = FALSE)
  chartSeries(symb, subset = 'last 3 months', name=x)
  plot(addBBands())
  plot(addMACD())
}
doGraph("AAPL")
```

Comment: Or, better yet, put them in the `chartSeries` call: `chartSeries(symb, subset='last 3 months', name=x, TA="addBBands();addMACD()")`.

Comment: Thanks Guys -- both solutions work. However, I'd like to understand why this happens? If I put both calls in the function, `addBBands()` gets skipped. However, if I call `addBBands()` afterwards, it appears with no issues. Is there an underlying restriction that I'm missing here? Any input appreciated!

Comment: @MarkCukier did you click the links in my comment on my answer to the duplicate post?

Comment: @GSee -- no, I didn't even notice that there was a comment on the original question. I'm now reading R-SIG-Finance history... thanks for the links!