# Is it possible to build a quantmod chart incrementally and export the final result as a single-page pdf?

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I would like to produce a pdf of a chart produced with quantmod. For example,

```
library(quantmod)

data(sample_matrix)
d <- as.xts(sample_matrix)

pdf("chart1.pdf")
chartSeries(d$Open,TA=c(addTA(d$Close,on=1),addTA(d$High)))
dev.off()
```

The question is whether it is possible to produce a single-page pdf, like `chart1.pdf`, but using `addTA()` incrementally. To illustrate, the following code will create a three-page pdf, `chart2.pdf`; I would like to directly create the final page of that pdf, but without specifying the `addTA` calls in the original call to `chartSeries` as above.

```
pdf("chart2.pdf")
chartSeries(d$Open)
print(addTA(d$Close,on=1))
print(addTA(d$High))
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your chart in as many steps as you want, then use `dev.copy` to create a pdf of it.

```
library(quantmod)

data(sample_matrix)
d <- as.xts(sample_matrix)

chartSeries(d$Open)
addTA(d$Close,on=1)
addTA(d$High)
dev.copy(pdf, "chart2.pdf")
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks, but that produces an empty pdf for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: @RahulSavani Yes it worked for me.  Did you run the `dev.off()` line?

Comment: I did, but I suppose the problem was I had not run ``dev.off()`` previously and had some device still open. It worked fine in a clean workspace, thanks.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work from a script file called with Rscript. Any idea what to do for that case?

Comment: @RahulSavani [wrap the addTA calls in plot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18342756/967840)

Comment: They are wrapped in plots (which is anyway needed where I source the script with ``source`` in which case it works). Doesn't work for. Here's the complete code: ``library(quantmod);
data(sample_matrix);d <- as.xts(sample_matrix);
chartSeries(d$Open);plot(addTA(d$Close,on=1));plot(addTA(d$High));dev.copy(pdf,"chart.pdf");dev.off()``. Thanks for your patience!